# Setting *both* Value & Formula in EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus

Is there any way to set **both** the `Value` & `Formula` properties of a cell so that they persist into the written XLSX file?

Since EPPlus does not calculate the formulas (it relies on excel to do so), I am pre-calculating the result for the user.  This is so that if they do not open the file, but then re-upload it, the 'value' is not null.  The formulas are really simple.

**Note:**  `sheet.SetValue()` and `.Value` both reset the Formula property of the `ExcelCell` class,  so `.Value` must be called first.  See the source code for `ExcelCell.SetRichText()` to see it happening.

Here is almost the exact code from the test case:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(); // and setup code
var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); 
sheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 10; 
sheet.Cells["A2"].Formula = "=A1 * 3";
// Cell is OK now.  shows both ".Value" and ".Formula"

using (var s = new MemoryStream()) { 
    package.Save(s);
    var newPackage = new ExcelPackage(s);
    var newSheet = newPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    var cell = newSheet.Cells["A2"];
    // cell.Value == null
    // cell.Formula = "=A1 * 3"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of EpPlus version 4.0.1.1, there is an extension method `Calculate(this ExcelRangeBase range)`. Invoke it:

```
cell.Calculate();
```

and after that the `cell.Value` will return the expected result.

**UPDATE**

From [the official documentation](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation):

> EPPlus supports formula calculation from version 4. This means that
>   you can let EPPlus calculate the results of the formulas in a
>   workbook.
>
> This is done by calling the Calculate() method, which is available on
>   Workbook, Worksheet and Range level. When Calculate() is called EPPlus
>   will evaluate the result of the formula and store the result as the
>   Value of the cell - just like Excel do.

**Example**

```
using(var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\tmp.xlsx")))
{
   // calculate all formulas in the workbook
   package.Workbook.Calculate();
   // calculate one worksheet
   package.Workbook.Worksheets["my sheet"].Calculate();
  // calculate a range
  package.Workbook.Worksheets["my sheet"].Cells["A1"].Calculate();
}
```

**Known issues**

> The following features of Excel are currently not supported by EPPlus
>   when it comes to Formula caluclation: Array Formulas, the Intersect
>   operator, references to external workbooks.

Comment: I will have to take your word for it, since I'm not actively working on this project.  Can you link to the documentation covering this feature, if it exists?  Normally with EPPlus I just read the source to figure out what it really does, but I noticed someone added a `supported formulas` page to the docs.  Perhaps there is some guidance on using this feature (for future discoverers of this question).

Comment: EPPlus supports formula calculation from version 4. This is documented briefly in the readme file and the functionality is demonstrated in the samples project, which is available on codeplex. And - as mentionend above - the supported functions are listed in the documentation section.

Comment: @AndrewBacker, I have updated my answer in accordance with your request.

Comment: @Deilan Thanks for the update.  EP+ keeps getting better